# Web app deployed in JBOSS access via LAN/WiFi

Tags: jboss, web-deployment, lan, jboss-eap-6

I'm new to this server stuff, a web app is deployed on jboss-eap-6.4 and it works fine on localhost. Tried to access the webapp as (192.168.XXX.XXX:8080/myapp) through lan (WiFi) but end with Connection timeout. Is there any configurations to do with jboss server ?

Please, help me to resolve this. Thanks !

Comment: How did you start JBoss EAP?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins by calling 'standalone.conf.bat'

Comment: Try using `%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Thanks @JamesR.Perkins. It worked. Can you please explain why standalone.bat instead of standalone.conf.bat and  what is -b attribute ?

Comment: The `standalone.conf.bat` is the editable configuration imported into the `standalone.bat`. There should be a good description of the `-b` argument with `standalone.bat -h` :)

Comment: Thanks @JamesR.Perkins for your help :)